# How can I draw (using a computer) spaces that I can't parametrize easily?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, math-software

I am studying algebraic topology and I came around the following problem:

I have to describe the space obtained when I identify the circles marked with different letters in the following figure:

[image: Image extracted from "Topología Algebraica" by Vicente Muñoz and J.J. Madrigal, 2015]

I came to the conclusion that the resulting space is something which looks like a torus (due to the b circles)  with something attached that is constructed similar to the Klein bottle (due to the a circles).

I am wondering now how can I draw an space like this with a computer. Is there any specific program that I can use or the best way is to use some pen tablet (like Wacom's tablets)?

Comment: `b` gives you the torus (think about pulling the inner-`b` up then stretching it over to the bigger `b` and joining them. Now the `a`s do NOT form a tube, notice the direction of the arrows. Also TBH, paper and pen is always good.

Comment: The `a` bit.... it's a bit `Klein-bottle`-esque if you will, imagine brining the left `a` up, then making the right `a` slightly smaller (radius wise), then brining it up through the left `a`s surface and into the middle, then smoothly joining it.

Comment: @AlecTeal I know that they can't form a tube outside the torus because of what you said but I was thinking that the tube could go inside the torus because it seemed similar to me to the construction of the Klein bottle. I used pen and paper to get some drawings but I would like to know if there is any computer alternative to be able to put the pictures nicely in a latex file.

Comment: @AlecTeal It's from a Spanish book written by my teacher. The name is "Topología Algebraica" by Vicente Muñoz and Juan José Madrigal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is draw several steps. I consider identifiying the `b` rings as trivial, so start with this:

[image]
(This was actually going well until I added the torus)

A series of drawings, easily verified at each step is the way forward.

> **Note:** it is not a tube going through the torus (then it'd just be a 2-torus anyway). Can you see why? Try moving the right extrusion down to the opposite side of the left and then going "through" the torus.

---

### Drawing with a computer

You cannot use a single pare of parameters to parameterise this as it has 2 holes. Well... I'll investigate this (they're sort of holes, right?) For example the 2-torus has to be 2 partial toruses joined together along a boundary.

It's so complicated to do these things that I'd urge you not to try. This is why a lot of topology books actually have hand-drawn illustrations.

You learn tricks like:

- To draw a torus draw a big ) then a slightly smaller ( touching the big one at two points, and draw an oval around it.
- Bold around an edge between the surface and the background help add depth.
- Use a pencil first, then go over it in pen. (I struggle with this one)